# Performance Considerations When Using Large Custom Objects as Keys in C++ unordered_map

Tags: c++, hashmap, unordered-map

I'm working on a C++ project where I've defined a custom class to use as the key in an `unordered_map`. To do this, I overrode the `==` operator and provided a custom hash function. The following is a simplified version of my code.

During execution, I noticed that inserting key-value pairs into the `unordered_map` triggers the copy constructor of my custom class. This leads me to worry about potential performance issues, especially when dealing with large objects that contain significant amounts of data.

Coming from a background in Python and Java, where hash tables store references to objects rather than copying them, I'm unsure about the best practices for using hash tables in C++. Is there a more efficient way to handle large objects as keys to avoid the overhead of copying? What are the recommended practices for optimizing performance in such scenarios?

PS: I don't believe this is an option-based question. When dealing with objects that serve as keys and are significantly large—such as one encapsulating a large-sized vector of integers—there are undoubtedly conventional methods to avoid copying the key with each insertion. One approach I can think of involves using pointers. However, as I am just beginning to learn C++, I am not certain if this is the best method.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional> 

class MyClass {
private:
    int key;
    std::string value;

public:
    MyClass(int k, const std::string& v) : key(k), value(v) {}

    MyClass(const MyClass& obj) {
        std::cout << "copy constructor called" << std::endl;
        key = obj.key;
        value = obj.value;
    }

    // override operator== 
    bool operator==(const MyClass& other) const {
        return (key == other.key && value == other.value);
    }

    // hash function
    friend std::size_t hash_value(const MyClass& obj) {
        std::size_t seed = 0;
        std::hash<int> hasher;
        std::hash<std::string> strHasher;
        seed ^= hasher(obj.key) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed<<6) + (seed>>2);
        seed ^= strHasher(obj.value) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed<<6) + (seed>>2);
        return seed;
    }
};

namespace std {
    template <>
    struct hash<MyClass> {
        std::size_t operator()(const MyClass& obj) const {
            return hash_value(obj);
        }
    };
}

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<MyClass, int> map;

    MyClass c1(1, "1");
    MyClass c2(2, "2");
    MyClass c3(1, "1");
    std::cout << "------step 1-------" << std::endl;
    map[c1] = 1;
    map[c2] = 2;
    std::cout << "------step 2-------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << map[c3] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "------step 3-------" << std::endl;
    map[MyClass(5, "5")] = 5;
    std::cout << "------step 4-------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << (map.find(MyClass(4, "4")) != map.end()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "------step 5-------" << std::endl;
    auto p = std::make_pair(c1, 5);
    std::cout << "------step 6-------" << std::endl;
    map.insert(p);
    return 0;
}
```

print result:

```
------step 1-------
copy constructor called
copy constructor called
------step 2-------
1
------step 3-------
copy constructor called
------step 4-------
0
------step 5-------
copy constructor called
------step 6-------
```

Comment: Maybe, create the key on the heap and store a pointer to that object in the map.

Comment: Depends on your use case, you could make your class movable, you could store a pointer instead, you could just not worry about it

Comment: Opinion-based questions are off-topic, see [help/on-topic]. If you have a large object as a key, you are likely doing it wrong. I'm also pretty sure Python and Java have mechanisms to prevent mutation of the key, such as immutable strings that are effectively copied every time you "mutate" it.

Comment: @PasserBy In Python, a dictionary key must be hashable, meaning it overrides the __hash__ function. It is entirely acceptable for the key to be mutable. In contrast, Java allows any class to be used as a key in a HashMap. However, if you want the keys to work as expected, you must override the equals and hashCode methods (otherwise it will use "memory address" to be hashcode). For instance, you can use List<Integer> as a key in a hashmap. Although the key itself is mutable, it is standard practice to adhere to the contract by not modifying the fields of a key that is stored in a hashmap.

Comment: @PasserBy I don't believe this is an option-based question. When dealing with objects that serve as keys and are significantly large—such as one encapsulating a large-sized vector of integers—there are undoubtedly conventional methods to avoid copying the key with each insertion. One approach I can think of involves using pointers. However, as I am just beginning to learn C++, I am not certain if this is the best method.

Comment: `std::unordered_map` supports `emplace`; this allows you to construct keys in-place or use a cheap(er) move operation instead of a copy.

Comment: But it is. You are repeatedly asking for "best" methods to achieve this, which is a question of opinion. Well, my opinion was stated already: you're likely doing something wrong if you're worried about copying keys, the solution is don't do this. You will get many more differing opinions. If you're asking how to create a type with reference semantics, then ask that instead.

Comment: Also, python hashable objects [specifically requires immutability](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable): _"an object is hashable if it has a hash value which never changes during its lifetime."_

Comment: Keys simply should not be so large that you need to worry about copying them. If they are large in your application, you are probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::shared_ptr` of `MyClass` as the keys in your `unordered_map`. This would stop the copy.
The `MyClass` implementation remains mostly same. You can change the hashing as follows.

```
namespace std {
template <>
struct hash<std::shared_ptr<MyClass>> {
    std::size_t operator()(const std::shared_ptr<MyClass>& obj) const {
        return hash_value(*obj);
    }
};

template <>
struct equal_to<std::shared_ptr<MyClass>> {
    bool operator()(const std::shared_ptr<MyClass>& lhs, const 
    std::shared_ptr<MyClass>& rhs) const {
        return *lhs == *rhs;
    }
};
```

Here, `equal_to<std::shared_ptr<MyClass>>` dereferences the shared_ptrs and uses `MyClass::operator==` to compare the `MyClass` objects.

```
int main() {
    std::unordered_map<std::shared_ptr<MyClass>, int> map;

    auto c1 = std::make_shared<MyClass>(1, "1");
    auto c2 = std::make_shared<MyClass>(2, "2");
    auto c3 = std::make_shared<MyClass>(1, "1");
    std::cout << "------step 1-------" << std::endl;
    map[c1] = 1;
    map[c2] = 2;
    std::cout << "------step 2-------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << map[c3] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "------step 3-------" << std::endl;
    map[std::make_shared<MyClass>(5, "5")] = 5;
    std::cout << "------step 4-------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << (map.find(std::make_shared<MyClass>(4, "4")) != 
    map.end()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "------step 5-------" << std::endl;
    auto p = std::make_pair(c1, 5);
    std::cout << "------step 6-------" << std::endl;
    map.insert(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
------step 1-------
------step 2-------
1
------step 3-------
------step 4-------
0
------step 5-------
------step 6-------
```

As I see it, one of the main issues of using the `std::shared_ptr` as keys to an `std::unordered_map` is that if there are multiple pointers pointing to the same object, the map will still consider them as different keys.

Comment: Your last paragraph applies just as much to dumb pointers as to `std::shared_ptr`.  But I don't know why you mention it since the implementation you propose doesn't have that problem.

Comment: I mentioned it not for this particular case but in general for using pointers as keys to an unordered map. I realized this while coming up with the answer and thought it is an important consideration.